# Hook/parent/constrain to particle hair?

Tags: rigging, particles, constraints

Is there any way to hook, parent, or constraint something to a vertex of a particle hair strand? Such as a hair accessory dangling from a braid that needs to move with the hair?

Converting the hair to mesh isn't viable, as I then lose hair dynamics and have to rig some other way.

Scripting solutions are fine too. There must be some way to get the location of a particle hair vertex or vertices from the API. Then you could have an empty copy it or something?

Comment: As hair particles, it will be hard to do this. You can convert the hair to a mesh in the Modifiers tab though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found a method to do it. It's not perfect but it works :). It uses a ***Particle Instance Modifier***.
[image]
[image]

Add a *Cube* (place its origin point in the same place as emitter's origin point). Scale it along the Z axis, then Subdivide, so it has the same number of loop cuts as the number of segments of your hair particles. Go to *Object Mode* and apply its transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
[image]

Go to *Modifiers* header and give it a ***Particle Instance Modifier***. Enable the modifier's settings as pictured below. 
[image]

It may not work properly though. If something's wrong just rotate your *Cube* ***90 degress*** on the X axis (or Y, or Z, depending on your situation).
[image]

Now add an object which will be following your strands and rotate it perpendicular to your *Cube*. Select it, then the *Cube* and enter the *Edit Mode*. Select the opposite 3 vertices, as pictured below and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>*-->Make Vertex Parent*.
[image]

Go to *Object Mode* and place the following object (*Torus* in this case) wherever you want. Select a *Cube* and move it to another layer to see only the hair particles.
[image]

---

EDIT:
You may precisely parent any object to a chosen strand's segment. In *Edit Mode* select any vertices, then enable an option as pictured below (marked in red) to see where their location on the instance is. 
[image]
[image]

Add a new object and parent it to selected vertices.
[image]

Then place it on a proper segment's location.
[image]

Now the object copies the location of the strand's segment.
[image]

Comment: Nice try though. I think the key here is the "Create Along Paths" toggle. But it seems works for a particular controllable single hair only? Since It is still hard to target which hair stand you want to follow.

Comment: Excellent. The part in your edit is exactly what I needed.