# How to constrain hair particles to an object

Tags: rigging, particles, constraints, parent, hair

I'm looking for a way to modify hair particles similar to an armature system or the mesh deform modifier. In the screenshot below, I need the ends of the hair particles to follow the object. Is there a way to assign weights to the hair and parent it to the object? Or is there some other method of constraining the hair so that the ends of the hair follow the object? Hair dynamics don't seem to give any satisfactory results.

[image: I need the ends of the hair to follow the ring here]

I'm trying to achieve a ponytail effect in which the position of the ponytail will be determined by moving the ring object. The rest of the hair/ponytail would be created on a new particle system inside the ring object. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do this, but if there is, I would like to hear from you guys. Probably the main reason why I'm doing it this way is because the implementation of a hoodie would pose further complications :/

There is also another similar question here that deals with constraining objects to the hair, but I need it to be the other way around. Also, the answer to that question does not accommodate to my particular situation above.

[Hook/parent/constrain to particle hair?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36232/hook-parent-constrain-to-particle-hair)
[image: concept animation]

edit: I made a little animation on what I'm trying to achieve

[image: better concept animation]

edit: This animation is a bit better - it shows how using hair dynamics or rigid bodies or other simulations won't work for this. When you move the ring, it moves the hair. Like bones. Also, it seems as if the ends of the hair are *connected* to the ring. Is that even possible in Blender?